# Use webpack to compile Typescript and Sass to individual files

Tags: typescript, webpack, sass

This is my first time working with webpack and I want to use it on a project that uses no frameworks, so what I want to do is to be able to compile all my `.ts` files into a `main.js` file and also all my `.scss` files into a `style.css`.

> Once I have this setup I will also do some other things for production, such as minify the js and use postcss on my css file.

This is my `webpack.config.js` file:

```js
const path = require('path');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');

module.exports = {
  mode: "development",
  devtool: 'eval-source-map',
  entry: {
    main: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/ts/index.ts'),
    style: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/sass/style.scss'),
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public'),
    filename: '[name].js',
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        use: 'ts-loader',
        include: [path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/ts')]
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [
          MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: {
              sourceMap: true,
            },
          },
          {
            loader: 'sass-loader',
            options: {
              sourceMap: true,
            },
          }
        ],
        include: [path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/sass')]
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.js']
  },
  plugins: [
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: '[name].css',
    }),
  ]
}
```

Basically I was able to make it "kind of" work. When I run the script I get 3 files in my output folder, which is `main.js`, `style.css` but I also get `style.js`. I don't need the `style.js` file, but I believe it's there because of my output webpack config property.

Is there a way to fix this issue and get only the desired files?

> Also, I'm using the `MiniCssExtractPlugin` because it's what I saw on the tutorial I was following, but if it can be removed, I'm ok with it.

Answer (score 2):

There is no built-in way to remove this. Webpack is a bundler whose job is to generate bundled JS files. In fact, even if you have CSS or SASS files, it ends up converting those files into a JS files which then inject your styles using DOM API. The `MiniCSSExtractPlugin` is a plugin (more powerful than a simple Webpack loader) which simply extracts the main CSS code from this generated `style.js` file and the `style.js` file simply becomes a bare minimum file which does nothing if added to the HTML file. So, there is no harm in leaving it as it is.

However, if you really wish to delete this file, then you have two options. Either write your own Webpack plugin or simply run the `rm` command after building the project using Webpack CLI. Latter is simpler and often a common practice. Writing plugin may be an overkill for this.

Comment: That's nice to know. Like I mentioned, I'm new to this, so I didn't knew it. But yeah.. I'll leave the file there and will remove during the production process, where I use grunt to move files around and do some other things. Thanks